# Creating bean error if change Spring data jpa entity package

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I use `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` for get data from mysql.

When my project structure is (Project.java file is in application package) everything works well, but when I put Project.java entity file to entities package I got bellow exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'controller': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.gehive.microservice.data.repositories.ProjectRepository com.gehive.microservice.application.Controller.repo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'projectRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class com.gehive.microservice.data.entities.Project

work without exceptions:

[image]

if structure like this I got exception:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default `@ComponntScan` for Spring boot(the one that `@SpringBootApplication` inherits) scans the current package and all it's sub packages.

In the first case `Project.java` is in the same package as `Application.java`, so it's ok.

To make Project work from another package change the name to `com.gehive.microservice.application.entities` or whatever sub-package of the one with the main class.

Usually I keep the bootstraping class and all the configuration classes in package named `<com|org|etc>.<myCompany>.<myProject>` and then create the other packages as sub packages of this one.

Spring Data JPA has some other conditions related to the packages. Take a look at the [Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/)